# Setting the 'correct' pip3

Tags: linux, python-3.x, terminal, anaconda

I have Python 2.7 installed (by default) and also a Python3.x. I installed anaconda later. When I use pip3, it uses the pip3 for Python3.x  I guess. When I do  which pip3 on terminal, it shows user/bin/pip3. But I want it to use pip3 from anaconda. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: don't know about `anaconda`, but have you looked into [docs](https://conda.io/docs/using/pkgs.html#install-a-package)?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I want to set the pip3 from anaconda as default on my terminal...

Comment: why not just use anaconda for installing packages?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Tried that, didn't work on jupyter ;-;

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the Anaconda prompt:

```
conda install pip3
```

If that doesn't work, in the same prompt try

```
pip install pip3
```

Comment: When I do pip install pip3, it says "No matching distribution found"